# Equation in integers of irrational degree

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Are there any algebraic irrational numbers in $\{log_xy|x,y\in\mathbb{N},x,y\geq2\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem,

Suppose your set produces an algebraic irrational number
$ \log_xy = z,$ then $ x^z = y $ is transcendental by the theorem . But $y$ is a natural number, which are algebraic by nature. Thus we have arrived at a contradiction.